# VB.NET, mostrar en combobox los datos de una consulta select

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Hola buenas noches a todos, tengo un metodo que permite buscar un valor, si lo encuentra, me trae los datos asociados y los pasa a diferentes controles, a los textbox, labels ningun drama, pero para mostrar en el combobox no funciona, no muestra el valor en el combobox. el metodo es este:

```vb
Try

        Dim confirmacion As DialogResult

        Dim queryBusqueda As String = "SELECT * FROM tbl_funcionario_soporte WHERE rut_Funcionario=@rut_funcionario"

        comando = New MySqlCommand(queryBusqueda, conexionMYSQL)

        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rut_funcionario", txtRut.Text)

        da.SelectCommand = comando

        da.Fill(dt)

        If (dt.Rows.Count <> 0) Then
            cmdEliminar.Enabled = True
            cmdActualizar.Enabled = True
            Button5.Enabled = False
            Button1.Enabled = False
            txtRut.Enabled = True
            txtNombre.Text = dt.Rows(0)(4).ToString
            txtIdDpto.Text = dt.Rows(0)(1).ToString
            cmbDepartamento.SelectedItem = dt.Rows(0)(5).ToString
            'cmbDepartamento.SelectedValue = dt.Rows(0)(1).ToString
            'txtIdProfesion.Text = dt.Rows(0)(1).ToString
            ComboBox1.SelectedValue = dt.Rows(0)(1).ToString
            txtDireccion.Text = dt.Rows(0)(6).ToString
            txtCelular.Text = dt.Rows(0)(7).ToString
            txtAnexo.Text = dt.Rows(0)(8).ToString
            txtEmail.Text = dt.Rows(0)(9).ToString
            txtcontraseña.Text = dt.Rows(0)(10).ToString
            TextBox1.Text = dt.Rows(0)(2).ToString
            'cmbTipoPermiso.SelectedValue = dt.Rows(0)(6).ToString
            'btnNuevaBusqueda.Visible = True

            lblBuscador.Visible = False

            desbloquearEdicion()

            conexionMYSQL.Close()
        Else
            confirmacion = MessageBox.Show("Rut no Existe en la Base de Datos ¿Desea Registrarlo Ahora?", "Sistema de Gestión de Incidencias", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

            If confirmacion = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                Try
                    desbloqearControles()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.Message)
                Finally
                    conexionMYSQL.Close()
                End Try
            ElseIf confirmacion = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
                conexionMYSQL.Dispose()
                txtRut.Text = ""
                txtRut.Focus()
                Return
            End If
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conexionMYSQL.Dispose()
    End Try
    conexionMYSQL.Close()
```

y paso los valores asignadolos de esta manera:

```vb
            txtIdDpto.Text = dt.Rows(0)(1).ToString
            cmbDepartamento.SelectedItem = dt.Rows(0)(5).ToString
```

EL METODO QUE USO para cargar el combobox (lo llamo en el load del form) es este:

```vb
  Public Sub cargaDepartamentos()

    'LIMPIAMOS Y ACTUALZIAMOS EL COMBOBOX
    Me.cmbDepartamento.Items.Clear()

    conexionMYSQL = New MySqlConnection

    conexionMYSQL.ConnectionString = ("server=localhost;User Id=soporte;database=db_incidencias_muniquel;password=123")

    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader

    Dim comando As MySqlCommand

    Try

        conexionMYSQL.Open()

        Dim query As String = ("SELECT id_departamento, nombre_departamento FROM tbl_departamentos")

        comando = New MySqlCommand(query, conexionMYSQL)

        dr = comando.ExecuteReader

        While dr.Read
            Dim nombre_departamento = dr.GetString("nombre_departamento")

            cmbDepartamento.Items.Add(nombre_departamento)
        End While

        conexionMYSQL.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conexionMYSQL.Dispose()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Saludos a todos, que tengan una excelente jornada y desde ya gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Si lo que desea es que al momento de cargar los datos, el valor que trae de la base de datos se seleccione el combobox con ese valor, porque veo que toma dos valores distintos? o sea para el `txtIdDpto.Text = dt.Rows(0)(1).ToString` y para el `cmbDepartamento.SelectedItem = dt.Rows(0)(5).ToString` en uno toma la posición `1` y en otra toma la `5` no se supone que un valor de esos dos es el que pertenece al departamento.

Comment: Es necesario que muestres como estás cargando los datos en el combobox para que te podamos dar una respuesta exacta. Pero como pista, `SelectedItem` no es casi seguro un string, sino algun otro tipo de datos (`DataRow` puede ser?)

Comment: gracias chicos, edite la pregunta para añadir como cargo el combobox

Comment: supongo que esto es winforms no?

Comment: si, winforms, vb.net y mysql